# Refactor code to remove uuid

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

Hi I have some code generated inside a JSP tag, which uses the jQuery data function to associate data with a div.

I have used a UUID to link the jQuery script to the div on the page.
However this approach is ugly and inconvenient and I was wondering if there was a way to refactor it to not require the UUID.

The code looks like this.

```
    for(DomainObject domainObject : domainObjects){
//...
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        out.println("<div id='" +uuid + "' class='" + divClass + "'>");

        // Write out the details of this domain object.
        out.println(/*...*/);

        // Associate data with the div
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#"+uuid+"').data('domainObject'," + jsonSerializer.exclude("class").serialize(domainObject) + ")</script>");
        out.println("</div>");
//...
    }
```

Comment: do you need the complete domain object inside your js ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use jQuery 1.4.3 there is a very easy way to associate data to an element in the dom.  As of 1.4.3 jQuery will inspect the elements for any [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and automatically make them available via .data("key")

```
<div class='myClass' data-domainObject='{"Name": "I am in your data!"}'>
    Domain Object
</div>

$(function(){
    alert($(".myClass").data("domainObject").Name);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tqdh/)

Since it appears you are just using the script tag to add data to the element this option might be suitable and look something like this (note I have no experience with jsp):

```
for(DomainObject domainObject : domainObjects){
//...

        out.println("<div class='" + divClass + "' data-domainObject='" + jsonSerializer.exclude("class").serialize(domainObject)+ "'>");

        // Write out the details of this domain object.
        out.println(/*...*/);
        out.println("</div>");
//...
    }
```

Comment: ah yes I saw this option before.  I wasn't sure if it was a good idea given that it's not valid until HTML5. I guess it really doesn't matter though, I might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways (examples are using JSTL/EL)

1. Use ID of domain object instead, if any.

   ```
   <div id="do_${domainObject.id}">
   ...
   <script>$('#do_${domainObject.id}').foo();</script>
   ```
2. Use a loop counter.

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${domainObjects}" var="domainObject" varStatus="loop">
       <div id="do_${loop.index}">
       ...
       <script>$('#do_${loop.index}').foo();</script>
   </c:forEach>
   ```

Note that the ID **must** start with an alphabetic character. ID's starting with a digit are illegal. UUID may return ID's starting with a digit.

Comment: ah right, I totally missed that. Yes you're right, some of them do start with a digit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is so ugly about it. Maybe you just want a shorter id?

A UUID is unique universally.  This far exceeds the requirements for IDs on elements in an HTML page - that they are unique within the page.

It is easy and appropriate to create page-unique IDs that are 1 or 2 digits long.  Your JSP needs to replace `randomUUID()` with `randomPageId()`, which returns a sequence of d1, d2, d3, or whatever.